# php jquery save checkbox dynamically

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox

im bit confused how to save checkbox value dynamically in 1 table!

database:

```
id  PERSON   check
--------------------
1   Person1  1
2   Person2  1
3   Person3  1
4   Person4  0
```

HTML code:

```
<form id="availability">
Person1 <input type="checkbox" id="person1" value="1" checked>
Person2 <input type="checkbox" id="person2" value="1" checked>
Person3 <input type="checkbox" id="person3" value="1" checked>
Person4 <input type="checkbox" id="person4" value="0">
</form>
```

jquery:

```
$('#availability').submit(function(){
  $.post('include/setting.php', {
      person1: $('#person1').val(),
      person2: $('#person2').val(),
      person3: $('#person3').val(),
      person4: $('#person4').val(),
  }, function(data){

    if(data.success) {

    } else {

    }
  }, 'json');
  return false;
})
```

PHP:

```
$person1 = $_POST['person1'];
$person2 = $_POST['person2'];
$person3 = $_POST['person3'];
$person3 = $_POST['person4'];
$db->query("UPDATE person SET id='???");
```

Comment: Why are you saving the value and not the checked status?  If you want checked status you can use `$('#person1').is(':checked');`

Comment: i want save/update multiple checkbox (if the checked or not) value to database

Comment: as far as I know, the value of your checkbox isn't the checked status, it's the value.  Do you want to save the checked status?

Comment: yeap! if its checked or not check the value will be 1 or 0 so both to save

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach isn't the cleanest or most modular, but it can work. Here are direct modifications to your code which should help it out:

HTML

```
<form id="availability">
    Person1 <input type="checkbox" id="person1" value="1">
    Person2 <input type="checkbox" id="person2" value="1">
    Person3 <input type="checkbox" id="person3" value="1">
    Person4 <input type="checkbox" id="person4" value="1">
</form>
```

javascript

```
$( '#availability' ).submit( function()
{
    $.post(
        'include/setting.php',
        {
            persons: {
                person1: ( $( '#person1:checked' ).length ? 1 : 0 ),
                person2: ( $( '#person2:checked' ).length ? 1 : 0 ),
                person3: ( $( '#person3:checked' ).length ? 1 : 0 ),
                person4: ( $( '#person4:checked' ).length ? 1 : 0 )
            }
        },
        function( data )
        {
            if( data.success )
            {

            }
            else
            {

            }
        },
        'json'
    );

    return false;
} );
```

PHP

```
<?php
foreach( $_POST['persons'] as $personIdentifier => $checked )
{
    //DO PROPER CHECKS AND ESCAPING OF INCOMING DATA!!!!!!!
    $db->query( "UPDATE person SET check = {$checked} WHERE PERSON = '{$personIdentifier}'" );
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. i tried your code, its not updating the database value :( any idea why?

Comment: Without access to your server to verify all info you gave us and troubleshoot, no, I don't have an idea.

Comment: are you available for a chat. so i cud give you as many as i can if u ok :) http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php

Comment: sittin' in chat for about 10 minutes or so now...don't see ya

Comment: sorry i was there waiting for u too before u came :D. anyway i sorted it out.. thanks for ur help tho ;)

Comment: @JAAulde what's include in settings.php?

Comment: @RyanOscar I couldn’t tell you. It’s where the OP was sending the data. The question was front-end related, so I didn’t ask

Answer (score 3):

You do not need a form that processes all of the inputs at one time, but only send a request for the modified field without using any form.

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
  $.post('include/setting.php', {
    id: this.id,
    value: $(this).attr("checked")?1:0
  }, function(data){
    if(data.success) {
    } else {
    }
  }, 'json');
  return false;  
});
```

and for PHP:

```
$db->query("UPDATE person SET value=".$_POST['value']." WHERE  id=".$_POST['id'] );
```

Also remember to always escape queries with mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: This definitely makes sense, but only if the OP intends to have the value changed on every check or uncheck, which may not be the case.

Comment: then what does mean "how to save checkbox value dynamically" ?

Comment: @justkt thanks. something like i wanted. i followed your code, but it doesnt update the database. it didnt pick up the id

Comment: Yes, that's my answer ! I don't understand why updating all users on modification. If there was 1000 persons ?

Answer (score 2):

To pass a 0 if unchecked and a 1 if checked, you can use the [is](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method with the [:checked selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) to determine the checked value as a boolean then use the [ternary operator](http://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/javascript/ternary.php) to set your JSON value to 1 or 0 depending on the result.

```
$('#availability').submit(function(){
  $.post('include/setting.php', {
      "person1" : $('#person1').is(':checked') ? 1 : 0,
      "person2" : $('#person2').is(':checked') ? 1 : 0,
      "person3" : $('#person3').is(':checked') ? 1 : 0,
      "person4" : $('#person4').is(':checked') ? 1 : 0,
  }, function(data){

    if(data.success) {

    } else {

    }
  }, 'json');
  return false;
})
```

Comment: thanks! and how do i pass it to php? and save the value 0 and 1?

Comment: You are already posting it to your PHP file, correct?  See if your PHP file is receiving the correct data, first, then iterate through and save as you've shown above.